# A twist to the Belt Problem: find the radius of two equal sized circles given the belt length

Tags: trigonometry

I'm really stuck here.  I've seen formulas for the Belt problem that describe how to find the length of the belt that crosses over between two (normally unequal) circles (cogs, gears?).

My problem is the reverse in that I know the length of the belt.  and I'm not to sure how to go about finding the various angles and radius to draw the circles in the correct positions.  I have the distance between the two circles.  The two circles have equal radius too.

[image: desc]

Comment: Hint: If both circles have the same radius, the belt will run parallel between those two circles, then there is no need calulating any angles=)

Comment: When you say you have the distance between the circles, do you mean you have the distance  between their centres?  Or do you mean that you know the minimum distance between points on the two circles? Or something else? What you mean by the distance will not change the analysis much, but what is known should be clear.

Comment: @flawr sorry the diagram is not that clear after looking at it again.  The belt is crossing over in the center of the two circles, not in parallel, so it is a figure of eight.

Comment: @André the distance between the centers of the two circles is going to be fixed.  Sorry I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

Let us call the point where the belt forms an $x$ (right in the center) $M$.

Note that $MCA$ is a triangle with a right angle at $C$. Let us call the anlge $CAM = \alpha$. Then the total belt length is given by

$$B = 2(2\pi-2\alpha)R+4 \sin(\alpha)\frac P 2$$

and looking again at that triangle you notice $$\cos(\alpha) = \frac{P/2}{R}$$

With these two equations, you should be able to solve for $\alpha$ and $P$ (the distance between the two centers of the circles).